# Accessible Namespaces in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer-2010

I'm having a conceptual issue here with the ASP.net framework.. This poster, to which I have linked below, outlines the .NET framework. Listed are all of the namespaces. Are all of these namespaces importable and useable in Visual Web Developer?

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LhsOitzo1aE/UIUA77SEjqI/AAAAAAAAABQ/ikzJ8R0gT1I/s1600/net35_namespaces_poster_lores%255B1%255D.png

Comment: *importable* - yes. *useable* - no. why would something like `system.windows.controls` be useable in `asp.net`?

Comment: Ok, thank you. Why is it possible to import them if they are not useable? Why would they be listed on this chart? Are their properties accessible? I'm not understanding this.

Comment: They are importable but not always usable. You don't need namespaces from specific WPF or WinForms in a web-application and vice versa.

Comment: How do I differentiate between what's useable and not?

Comment: because something like `system.data.common` could be usable to manage datareaders in asp.net. but `windows.forms.button` cannot be used in context of asp.net. you have to be context-aware to be able to distinguish.

Comment: so is there no definitive organizational structure to what namespaces are accessible? am i playing a context-sensitive guessing game?